# Math.NET - return matrix as string by row

Tags: math.net

I'm using Math.Net (http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) to work with matrices.

I need a method that returns a matrix as a string.

So if my matrix looks like this:

```
{{1.0, 2}
 {3  , 4}}
```

I need my return string to equal

```
"1 2 3 4"
```

Here is my code

```
var M = Matrix<double>.Build;
var mMatrix = M.DenseOfArray(new[,] {{ 1.0, 2 },
                                     { 3  , 4}});

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var m in unitMatrix.Enumerate())
{
   builder.Append(m + " ");
}
return builder.ToString();
```

This returns "1 3 2 4"

How do I make it return "1 2 3 4"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate row by row using `mMatrix.EnumerateRows()`, and then enumerate through all the values of each row. For example, you could write this as:

```
String.Join(" ", mMatrix.EnumerateRows().SelectMany(x => x.Enumerate()))
```

or if it is ok to build up an intermediate array:

```
String.Join(" ", mMatrix.ToRowWiseArray())
```

Alternatively you could use the existing string formatting functions, even though they are a bit weird to use, e.g.:

```
mMatrix.ToMatrixString(int.MaxValue,0,int.MaxValue,0,"","",""," "," ", x => x.ToString())
```